# Is there a way to remove ALL key bindings in VSCODE?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to delete all the shortcut keys first, after that, I want to set only a few keys that I need.

Comment: why? just don't use any of the default key bindings. Be aware that you need a lot of key bindings to just do the basic edit things. Just define the new ones you need/want.

Comment: @rioV8 No command to delete all the keys?

Comment: you can delete the json file containing all the default keys but you get them back you update. Still a big WHY?

Comment: I have already have both you said before asking. So your answer is NO to MY question. thank you.